# Fail to find an NFT via computed NFTokenPage ID as per docs on XRPL

Tags: nft, xrp

I'm working on a concept of a NFT search on xrpl and fail to perform a fundamental test - finding existing NFTs via computed NFTokenPage ID (https://xrpl.org/nftokenpage.html#finding-nftokens).

The ID seems to be valid per description, and NFTs are there. I'm using the tool on the page (https://xrpl.org/websocket-api-tool.html#ledger_entry-by-object-id) to complete queries using ledger method.

Are there any actual code/samples for NFTokenPage entries other than the format doc? Any help would be appreciated.

Using the testnet, I can see NFTs in accounts using the same tool via account methods.